# Why are my parent styles loading after my child styles?

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, parent-theme, sass

I am trying to build a child theme that uses SCSS. However, every time I make changes and recompile my stylesheet, it gets overridden by the parent stylesheet. This is because, in the head of my site, the parent styles are loading after the child styles. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the child styles to load last. I've looked at similar questions here and elsewhere and I cannot get it to work. This is what I have in my parent theme in library > theme.php:

```
if (!function_exists('slam_scripts_and_styles')) { 
function slam_scripts_and_styles() {
  global $wp_styles; // call global $wp_styles variable to add conditional wrapper around ie stylesheet the WordPress way
  if (!is_admin()) {
    $theme_version = wp_get_theme()->Version;

    // register main stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slam-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css', array(), $theme_version, 'all' );

  }
}
}
```

And this is in my child functions.php:

```
//Get UIC Child Theme Styles
function uic_styles() {

    wp_dequeue_style( 'slam-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css', array(), $theme_version, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'uic-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uic_styles', 10 );
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I feel like I've been banging my head against a wall for several hours.

Comment: I faced a similar issue recently and realized that it was because I had the parent theme active on the dashboard under Appearance > Themes instead of the child theme. Also confirm your file is in the child theme and not the parent theme. To troubleshoot, try seeing if you can add a stylesheet that's something other than style.csss it's not the same as the parent theme's. If you can enqueue a different stylesheet just fine - then it has something to do with style.css itself.

Comment: The child theme is active, and it will pick up unique styles. But any time I try to override an existing parent style, nothing happens because the parent file loads last.

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory_uri() refers to the path of your current project, so perhaps where you're dequeue-ing the stylesheet, you're pointing at the parent and not the child theme, therefore there is nothing for it to remove. Try changing that to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

Comment: But I am trying to dequeue the parent stylesheet...

Comment: Wait, you're already using get_template_directory_uri - can I ask what theme this is?

Comment: You should be able to have your style.css in the child theme in the same place automatically overwrite the parent's without having to write any code in the child theme's functions.php - testing this on the TwentyThirteen theme. The child theme's style.css should overwrite the parent's without issue - if this is not happening, it might be a theme specific issue.

Comment: Yes, in theory that's how it should work. But it's not working that way. The parent styles are loading after the child styles and thus, none of my child style's override the parent styles...

Comment: Btw, the parent theme is JointsWP.

Comment: I downloaded JointsWP, and it looks like in your functions, you're trying to remove the parent theme's style.css in library/css and just re-name the identifier but it's really the same exact path in your child theme. With your code, it was loading both the parent and child as you said, but without any code, just having the style.css be in the same location in the child overwrites it so I don't understand, is it that you want to change the identifier? Change slam-stylesheet to uic-styles because the overwriting should already be taking place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17218/discussion-between-rachievee-and-mcography).

Comment: is the `slam_scripts_and_styles` function in your first snippet being called as part of an `add_action()`? if not, it should be. if so, which one?

Comment: @karpstrucking Yes it is. In my parent functions.php I have this: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slam_scripts_and_styles', 999);`

Comment: Ah, that'll do it. The 999 is the priority level. Scripts load lowest to highest. The priority of the child theme is 10 (the default) so it is being loaded first, then the parent (999). Change your child to 999 or higher and it should be fixed